# Are DECT cordless phones interchangeable?

Tags: telephony

I would like to replace a Gigaset SL400 with a Panasonic KX-TPA50. Both phones are  DECT. Since DECT is a standard, does that mean the new phone should just work with my current base station?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DECT 6.0 is a standard, but many vendors' implementations are proprietary.

See [Digital Enhanced Cordless Telecommunications](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_Enhanced_Cordless_Telecommunications#DECT_6.0):

> DECT 6.0 products do not support "GAP"; therefore, phones of differing
>   brands are not guaranteed to work together. For example, a GE 28105EE1
>   DECT 6.0 headset will not receive calls if registered to a Uniden base
>   unit.

Also, the Panasonic model is a SIP phone, and I see no mention of SIP in the specifications of the Gigaset model.

Comment: What are the consequences of a phone being SIP? Does it mean that it connects through WIFI? I am having a lot of trouble figuring out the basic concepts of VoIP... Some websites are full of buzzwords, while others are deeply technical. Could you point me to useful resources? I have a solid background on programming, so I hope I will be able to understand everything.

Comment: SIP, primarily, is a protocol for managing VoIP, but it is also used for other things like video. It is used for call set up and tear down, etc. Basically, it is how the phone is managed. You should ask another question regarding VoIP, but don't make it too broad or require an answer which could fill a book.